# unable to host flask app on a specific ip and port

Tags: python, flask

I wanted to host my flask app on a specific port but the method I am using is not working. What I did is assign the `host` and `port` properties in my `socket.run()`. When I go to the specified address the page doesn't load. Where did I go wrong and how can I properly host a flask app with specific ip address and port. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** when I run the app with `python app.py` it works but when I run it with `flask run` it doesn't work.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blahBlah'
socket = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=7000)
```

Comment: Actually it is working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Flask version 0.11, setting the port param will not take affect unless config variable SERVER_NAME is set and debug=True.

Your regular Flask app will be running on default (localhost:5000).

Therefore the code should look like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blahBlah'
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1:8000'
socket = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket.run(app, debug=True)
```

See Flask ref for more information: [flask API](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.run)

**Edit:**

Above code example will work so forth your code is structured:

```
project
    app.py
    templates
        index.html
```

To run the code say:

```
python app.py
```

Running the code with the flask tools (flask run) will run the app and not the SocketIO part.

**The right way**

The right way to run the code is to do like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='BlaBla'
    )
    socket = SocketIO(app)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

    return app
```

Then in the shell run:

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
```

Now you can run the flask app with the flask command:

```
flask --app app --debug run
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get error ```UserWarning: The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work as intended in some browsers. Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead.```

Comment: @seriously I have added a "the right way" for running the app.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u are hosting something else on that specific port or on that specific ip or try to replace the socket.run by app.run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).